# WMSLayerInfo is not defined - arcgis 4.13

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Folks, just started using arcgis today and attempting to add a wms layer from geoserver.  I am using the javascript api v 4.13.

I started with this example:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-wms/live/index.html

Then proceeded to add the WMS layer as follows (I added the section // TEST - START to END):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>WMSLayer - 4.13</title>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/"></script>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/WMSLayer",
        "esri/layers/WMSLayerInfo",
        "esri/geometry/Extent"
      ], function(Map, SceneView, WMSLayer, WMSLayerInfo, Extent) {
        var layer = new WMSLayer({
          url: "https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service",
          sublayers: [
            {
              name: "OSM-WMS"
            }
          ]
        });

        var map = new Map({
          basemap: {
            baseLayers: [layer]
          }
        });

        var view = new SceneView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map
        });

        // TEST - START
    var layer1 = new WMSLayerInfo({
        name: 'sf:test1',
        title: 'sf:test1'
    });

    var resourceInfo = {
        extent: new Extent(3, 4, 5, 6, {
        wkid: 2236
    }),
        layerInfos: [layer1]
    };

    var wmsLayer = new WMSLayer('https://myserver/geoserver/sf/wms', {
        resourceInfo: resourceInfo,
        visibleLayers: ['sf:test1']
    });

    map.addLayers([wmsLayer]);

    // TEST - END



      });
      /***********************************
       * Data attribution:
       *  OpenStreetMap WMS by terrestris GmbH and Co. KG. Following sources were used:
       *  (c) OpenStreetMap contributors (http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)
       *  (c) OpenStreetMap Data (http://openstreetmapdata.com)
       *  (c) Natural Earth Data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com)
       *  (c) ASTER GDEM 30m (https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp)
       *  (c) SRTM 450m by ViewfinderPanoramas (http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/)
       *  (c) Great Lakes Bathymetry by NGDC (http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/greatlakes/)
       *  (c) SRTM 30m by NASA EOSDIS Land Processes Distributed Active Archive Center (LP DAAC, https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/)
       *********************************/
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am receiving the error "WMSLayerInfo is not defined".  I know its probably something very basic but I cannot find the answer online.  Thank you before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your require statement, you are trying to load `"esri/layers/WMSLayerInfo"` module **which does not exists in Arcgis Javascript API v4.x**

Just remove it from the list of modules you are trying to load.

```
require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/WMSLayer",
        "esri/geometry/Extent"
      ], function(Map, SceneView, WMSLayer, Extent) {

})
```

Dont forget to remove any references to `WMSLayerInfo` in your code and be sure to use the [ArcGIS Javascript API v4.x documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/).

Comment: Below the Radar, thank you for the info!  What would be the correct way to load a WMS Geoserver layer in v4.x?  Also forgot to mention the geoserver layer is in EPSG 2236.  Thank you.

Comment: This is another question, so please create a new question for that.

Comment: The link you provided in your question shows how to do it.

Comment: Below the Radar, could not get that sample to work with geoserver, I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311278/adding-geoserver-wms-layer-using-arcgis-javascript-4-x  Thank you.