# Adding geoserver wms layer using arcgis javascript 4.x

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to add a geoserver layer to arcgis javascript 4.x.  Here is what I have so far:

```
var layer1 = new WMSLayerInfo({
    name: 'sf:layer01',
    title: 'sf:layer01'
});

var resourceInfo = {
    extent: new Extent(275935.148501, 2038404.844184, 276182.595821, 2038680.709887, {
    wkid: 2236
}),
    layerInfos: [layer1]
};

var wmsLayer = new WMSLayer('https://myserver/geoserver/sf/wms', {
    resourceInfo: resourceInfo,
    visibleLayers: ['sf:layer01']
});

map.addLayers([wmsLayer]);
```

So far, I found out that the [WMSLayerInfo object has been deprecated in 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308152/wmslayerinfo-is-not-defined-arcgis-4-13).  Also how do I tell it to use EPSG: 2236 for this layer if I am using the normal streets base map:

```
var map = new Map({
                basemap: "streets",
                layers: [miabasemaplayer]
            });
```

Any help would be appreciate.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi. This isn't an ArcGIS Runtime question. Could you remove the tag please?

Comment: I dont think you can map WMS images that is projected in EPSG: 2236 over a basemap that is in EPSG: 3857. Does your geoserver enable serving WMS in 3857?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `spatialReference` parameter when declaring the `WMSLayer`?